# trouble setting checkboxes based on array

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, checkbox

I'm trying to check boxes on a form based on what's in an array.

```
var day = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Here's the html:

```
    <div id="daysoftheweek" class="control-group uncheckit">
        <label class="control-label" for="thedaysoftheweek">Which Days:</label>
        <div class="controls" name="thedaysoftheweek">
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="1"> Mon
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="2"> Tue
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="3"> Wed
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="4"> Thu
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="5"> Fri
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="6"> Sat
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="0"> Sun
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, with that array I'm trying to check Mon, Tue, Wed, and Thu. Console.log is showing that the loop is running fine.

This version only leaves the last one in the array checked, the Thu checkbox. If I end with 3, then it leaves Wed checked but not Mon and Tue.

```
for (_i = 0, _len = days.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  day = days[_i];
  $("input[name=days]").val([day]);
}
```

This one sets all of the radio buttons:

```
for (_i = 0, _len = days.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  day = days[_i];
  $("input[name=days]").val([day]).prop('checked', true);
}
```

Thanks for any ideas,
Charlie Magee

Comment: Radio buttons share names, checkboxes should have distinct names.

Comment: Do not forget `var` before `_i = 0`! And of course declare `day` variable too before use. You do not want an army of globals messing around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use value as a selector

```
var days= ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
for (var _i = 0, _len = days.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  $("input[name=days][value=" + days[_i] + "]").prop('checked', true);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AKVru/)

Also the array name should be `days`

Comment: Worked perfect. (The array was days. A typo when I wrote the question.) Thanks Arun.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that checkboxes should have distinct names (where radio buttons share a name attribute), you could do this:

```
var day = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$('input[name="days"]').filter(function (i) {
    return $.inArray(this.value, day) > -1
}).prop('checked', true)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Tk2bE/)**

Comment: This answer worked as well, but I selected the first one because it was a quicker fit with my existing code. Thanks j08691.